# getting signal SIGABRT in first IOS project, Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, xcode4, sigabrt

I am trying to create my first test app in IOs and everything I do gets me that error. I am using xcode 4.4.

The app is very simple. It has a button, and When I press it, a label and an imageview must appear.

My whole code is this:

```
ViewController.h


//
//  ViewController.h
//  helloWorld_04
//
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController{

    IBOutlet UILabel *label;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *Kant;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UILabel *label;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *Kant;
- (IBAction)buttonGuess:(id)sender;

@end
```

and my implementation file:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize label,Kant;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}



- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [label release];
    [Kant release];
    [super dealloc];
}
- (IBAction)buttonGuess:(id)sender {
    label.text=@"Hello World i am back!";
    UIImage *imageSource=[UIImage imageNamed:@"kantStair.png"];
    Kant.image=imageSource;
}
@end
```

My error log is this:

```
2012-08-23 13:38:50.030 helloWorld_04[537:c07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<ViewController 0x6a5e1f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key image.'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x14b2022 0xeb2cd6 0x14b1ee1 0x9c3022 0x934f6b 0x934edb 0x94fd50 0x23771a 0x14b3dea 0x141d7f1 0x23626e 0xdc1fc 0xdc779 0xdc99b 0x3b401 0x3b670 0x3b836 0x4272a 0x2d1b 0x13386 0x14274 0x23183 0x23c38 0x17634 0x139cef5 0x1486195 0x13eaff2 0x13e98da 0x13e8d84 0x13e8c9b 0x13c65 0x15626 0x2a22 0x2995)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

and it gets me that signal in that line:

```
//
//  main.m
//  helloWorld_04
//

//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

I have read several answers here but not found sollution to my problem, that why I made it a new question. I thought that it may be a problem with the connection so what I did on my own was to "darg and drop" my label and my image to "file's owner" but still getting the error.

Comment: Try ,
`self.label.text=@"Hello World i am back!";`
`self.Kant.image=imageSource;`

Comment: @BornSurvivor While that's good style, that's unlikely to be the problem. The OP syntax is acceptable, though your is superior.

Comment: @ghostrider The problem is undoubtedly a problem with how you've hooked up your various controls in Interface Builder. Looks like when you first hooked up stuff in Interface Builder, you used a control called `image` but have apparently now used `Kant` (which David H is quite right, it should be lower case).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at your error message, it looks like you have something defined as `image` in Interface Builder, but doesn't exist. E.g., maybe you have something like:

[image: Sample IB screen]

But you don't have a `image` property. Did you have one once upon a time, perhaps having renamed it to `Kant`? If you have something like this defined in Interface Builder, delete it (by tapping on the "x" next to the outlet that I've highlighted) and then link it up again to your new control.

---

**Update:**

You should definitely fix your bug above, and hopefully the above observation helps you find it. There is not a bug in your code, but rather the problem undoubtedly rests with your Interface Builder linkages.

But, having said that, if you're a new programmer, I hope you don't mind some unsolicited stylistic observations. Clearly, given that it is a matter of style, these can be debated, but I think these all represent either established or emerging iOS coding standards. Anyway, I might suggest that in the future:

1. Like David H suggested, you should use lower case variable names.
2. You probably should have `@synthesize` statements that either say `@synthesize label = _label`, or, if you're using Xcode 4.4 or later, just omit the `@synthesize` statement altogether. (I know that Interface Builder can generate a simple `@synthesize` statement for you, but it really is best practice to `@synthesize` with a unique instance variable name so you don't accidentally confuse instance variables with properties.)
3. You should reference your instance variables in `init` and `dealloc` methods (i.e. the variable name with the leading underscore) and elsewhere use the property (with the leading `self.`), as noted by Born Survivor.
4. You probably should omit the instance variables and let the `@synthesize` statement do these for you (so that if you make a typo, you don't accidentally end up with two instance variables).

Thus your code would then become:

```
//  ViewController.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

// note, no braces with instance variables defined
// once upon a time that was recommended by Apple, but no longer
// just let the following @property statements and the subsequent
// @synthesize statement generate the instance variables for you.

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *kant; // note the lower case "k"
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *label;

- (IBAction)buttonGuess:(id)sender;

@end
```

and

```
//  ViewController.m

#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize label = _label;  // note the @synthesize statement let's us define what the instance variable name should be, _label in this case
@synthesize kant  = _kant;

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [self setKant:nil];
    [self setLabel:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [_kant release];  // note I'm now using the instance variables that begin with the underscore
    [_label release];
    [super dealloc];
}

- (IBAction)buttonGuess:(id)sender
{
    self.label.text = @"Hello World i am back!";  // note, I'm using the properties with the preceding "self."
    UIImage *imageSource = [UIImage imageNamed:@"kantStair.png"];
    self.kant.image = imageSource;
}

@end
```

Comment: It was exaclty that. I have renamed my file. Thanks not only for the statement but for all that info.

Answer (score 0):

Its important in ObjectiveC to always name your variables with a lower case letter - because when you synthesize a variable like "foo" you get "-(id)foo;// the getter" and "-(void)setFoo:(id)val;//the setter". See how the setter uses a capital letter. So first thing you should do is rename 'Kant' to 'kant'. [by convention only Classes have initial capital letters, so you help others like me read your code by following the conventions.]

So first thing you do is change 'Kant' to 'kant', and then go back to the Interface builder view and re-wire the newly named variable to the UIImageView.

If that does not fix the problem, you have iswired 'kant' or there is some other oddity going on - add this line of code right before you set the image:

```
NSLog(@"kant has class %@", NSStringFromClass([kant class]) );
```

and lets see what it really is.

Comment: It's good style to use the lowercase variable name, but it won't cause the problem the OP is suffering from.